# FieldValue undefined when using functions and Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').FieldValue;

module.exports = functions.firestore
  .document('students/{studentId}')
  .onDelete(event => {
    const student = event.data.previous.data();
    const { id, semester } = student;
    const classId = student.class;
    const deleteObj = {};
    deleteObj[id] = FieldValue.delete(); //Line 12, this is where the error orccurs
    return admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('semesters')
      .doc(semester)
      .collection('students')
      .doc(classId)
      .update(deleteObj);
  });
```

Every time i run it I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined
    at module.exports.functions.firestore.document.onDelete.event (/user_code/deleteStudent.js:12:37)
```

Looking at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields) I cant really see what I am doing wrong?

```
// Get the `FieldValue` object
var FieldValue = require("firebase-admin").FieldValue;

// Create a document reference
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');

// Remove the 'capital' field from the document
var removeCapital = cityRef.update({
    capital: FieldValue.delete()
});
```

**Update**

So, using the web equivalent seems to work: `admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()`. But that seems like a bug since i'm in a nodejs environment? Can any Firebaser confirm or deny wether that is the case or not? I'd gladly file a bug report.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Turns out it was a mistake in the documentation, the correct import should have been `const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;`

**Update**

It should be said that Firebase responded within hours and are correcting the docs asap.

Comment: I wasted so much time on this. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Oh man I wish I found this answer sooner. Thanks for saving me.

Comment: Firestore is horribly documented. The only place the FieldValue import is documented is in a completely unrelated function's sample code at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects 
Need better documentation!

Answer (score 15):

It worked!

Require firebase-admin

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
```

Add this constant

```
const fieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;
```

Now use

```
fieldValue.delete()
```

For more reference : [otcollect.com/post](https://www.otcollect.com/collection/angularfire/page/mxeQ5NQY/how-to-delete-a-specific-field-in-firebase-firestore-document)

Comment: Just wondering how your answer is any different than that of @Chris above !

Comment: It's same but somehow that implementation didn't work for me!

Answer (score 12):

[Here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1803) you can find the solution on github.

Using typescript with

```
"firebase-admin": "^11.0.0"
"firebase-functions": "^3.22.0"
```

you have to use

```
import { FieldValue } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'
```

Same for `TimeStamp`