# Firestore - How to decrement integer value atomically in database?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore has recently launched a new feature to increment and decrement the integer values atomically.

I can increment the integer value using

For instance,
    `FieldValue.increment(50)`

But how to decrement ?

I tried using `FieldValue.decrement(50)`
But there is no method like decrement in FieldValue.

It's not working.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html?linkId=65365800&m=1

Answer (score 100, accepted):

To decrement the value in a field, do a negative increment. So:

```
FieldValue.increment(-50)
```

Comment: hahaha, I wonder why the OP didn't think of a negative parameter in the first place! Knowing the signed range of numeric datatypes is taken for granted nowadays... Anyway, in OP's defense, I would say that this `increment` method can be more aptly named as `tally`!  :P

Comment: `FieldValue` alone wasn't working. Then realized I need this `const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;`. Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47108530/2162226

Comment: Unfortunately the way to reach the correct method is slightly different on each platform. That's indeed the syntax on the Admin SDK for Node.js, although I usually do it as `admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-50)`.

Comment: Thanks for this, Google made no mention of this in their documentation.

Comment: is there any way to avoid negative value while decrementing? In my case, the field value is set to 20, when I decrement by 30, it goes to -10, which I don't want. I want the value to stop at 0.

Comment: There's no way to truncate the value, but you could reject that increment with security rules. If you're having trouble making that work, post a new question with what you tried.

Comment: @Soorya you can also get the value of the field first and then conditionally make update call if the value is (for example) equal or over 30.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're not accessing FieldValue from a Firestore instance. Eg. (in node.js with admin sdk)

```
admin.firestore().FieldValue.increment(-50) // Won't work
admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-50) // Will work
```

This did it for me.