# How to subtract data in firebase firestore in React-Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question.
I want to subtract A and B.
A is data in firebase firestore.
B is data in react native app.
Here is my code.

```
const purchaseStory = async () => {
    if (rabbit.rabbitAmount < price) {
      console.log('impossible');
    } else {
      console.log('do you want to buy?');

      //console.log(amount);
      setRabbitAmount({
        id: user.id,
        price, **// is B**
      });
    }
  };
```

```
export function setRabbitAmount({id, price}) {
  return userRabbitsCollection.doc(id).update({
    rabbitAmount: rabbitAmount - price, **// is A**
  });
}
```

current state: A is 100 / B is 35
expect result: A is changed to 65
current result: NaN

what should I do if I get the expected result?

I try to change the code

```
export function setRabbitAmount({id, price}) {
  return userRabbitsCollection.doc(id).update({
    rabbitAmount: rabbitAmount - price, **// is A**
  });
}
```

--> rabbitAmount: this.rabbitAmount-price

but the result is still NaN

Comment: Are you looking for [How to decrement integer in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621632/firestore-how-to-decrement-integer-value-atomically-in-database)?

Comment: Yes absolutely but I didn't find the answer.
However I found another way.
I withdraw a data using get- function. And then get the amount data from firestore. and then  I send the amount parameter. like this anyway finally I can get the result!

export function setRabbitAmount({id, price, rabbitAmount}) {
  return userRabbitsCollection.doc(id).update({
    rabbitAmount: (rabbitAmount = rabbitAmount - price),
  });
}