# With Firebase cloud functions, I can't delete a field from a map the same way I added it. Why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**Add Function**:

```
exports.newCampaign = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // get adventurer information
    const campaignName = data.campaignName;
    const timestamp = data.timestamp;

    const uid = context.auth.token.uid || null;

    // create a new document for the campaign
    var query = admin.firestore().collection(`Adventurers/${uid}/campaigns`).add({
        locations: [],
        name: campaignName
    })
    .then((docRef) => {
        admin.firestore().collection('Adventurers').doc(uid).update({
            [`campaignList.${docRef.id}`]: {
                id: docRef.id,
                name: campaignName,
                timestamp: timestamp
            }
        });

        return {
            id: docRef.id
        };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        return {
            error: "Error adding document: " + error
        };
    });

    return query;
});
```

When I call this, the Adventurers.uid.campaigns collection gets a new document with campaignId, and the Adventurers.uid.campaignList gets an attribute called campaignId. **Works as expected**

**Delete Function**:

```
exports.deleteCampaign = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // get adventurer information
    const campaignId = data.campaignId;
    const uid = context.auth.token.uid || null;

    // delete the document for the campaign
    var query = admin.firestore().collection(`Adventurers/${uid}/campaigns`).doc(campaignId).delete()
    .then((docRef) => {
        // delete campaign  from the campaign list
        admin.firestore().collection('Adventurers').doc(uid).update({
            [`campaignList.${campaignId}`]: Firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
        });

        return {};
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        return {
            error: "Error removing document: " + error
        };
    });

    return query;
});
```

When I call this, the document in the campaigns collection gets deleted, but the field in the campaignList does not get deleted. **Does not work as expected**. Since the document got deleted successfully, then I know that the function is getting the correct campaignId. I'm trying to delete in the exact same way as I added, so why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

Similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091940/fieldvalue-undefined-when-using-functions-and-firestore)

Since I'm running in a cloud function, I need to call admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete() instead of Firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete() in my delete function.