# Firebase security rules -- test server timestamp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-tools

Using `@firebase/rules-unit-testing` to test firebase security rules, how you test that a document's createdAt field is the current time? This is for Cloud Firestore.

#### Background

With firebase security rules, you can make sure a field is saved as the server timestamp.

```
match /collection/{docId} {
    allow create: if request.time == request.resource.data.createdAt
}
```

This security rule works. And if you were to write to the document in the browser, you would then do:

```js
firebase.firestore().collection('collection').add({
    createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})
```

However, the server timestamp method does not exist in `@firebase/rules-unit-testing`.

#### The code

Here's the boilerplate for the test setup, using Jest:

```
import { initializeTestApp } from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing'

const app = initializeTestApp({ projectId: 'id' })

test('some test', async () => {
    firebase.assertSuccees(
        app.firestore().collection('collection').add({
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        })
    )
})
```

The issue is that `firebase.firestore.FieldValue` is not defined (unlike in the browser example).

Furthermore, `app.firestore.FieldValue` is also not defined.

So how would you get the server timestamp to test this security rule?

#### Metadata

- firebase-tools: 9.3.0
- @firebase/rules-unit-testing: 1.1.9
- jest: 26.6.3
- Using the emulator

Comment: `FieldValue` is not included in the `rules-unit-testing` package, try importing the admin sdk and then use `admin.firestore.FieldValue` to access it, as described in this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091940/fieldvalue-undefined-when-using-functions-and-firestore). This should fix the issue you are facing. Try it out and let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and it wasn't resolved by using admin-sdk. It gives the error-
`Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in field createdAt in document col/doc`